# LWJGL OpenGL Display

Tags: opengl, runtime, lwjgl

When you try to close a display, generally I use

```
Mouse.destroy();

Keyboard.destroy();

AL.destroy();

Display.destroy();

System.exit(0);
```

But now I want to create a new one to replace it. I have a launcher program that has the start button. It runs off of lwjgl. When the user clicks start, it calls the destroy method, but first calls

```
Display.create()
```

Theoretically creating one display and closing the other. This instead crashes the Java Runtime Environment and prints an error. I was wondering if there was an already created method for doing this without crashing it, seeing as my method is not working. Here is the error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x050328e0, pid=3580, tid=5100
#
```

Answer (score 1):

The Display class is static.

What you're trying to do is create a class that already exists. If you want a launcher to launch your application, you should make it a completely separate program that launches it or introduce state management to keep track of what menu you are on.